# Nhibernate and enums

Tags: c#, mysql, database, nhibernate

Is a good habit to use enums with databases (NHibernate + mysql)? What are the advantages and disadvantages? Does it have influence to database efficiency?

Answer (score 2):

> Is a good habit to use enums with databases (NHibernate + mysql)?

I think it definitely makes sense from a programmer's perspective to use enums where applicable.  It makes for much more readable code and eliminates **"invalid"** values in your database.

> What are the advantages and disadvantages?
>   Does it have influence to database efficiency?

Advantages:

1. Readability from the code
2. Data integrity

Disadvantages:

1. Overhead in conversions of enums to database types.  Although this is probably negligible.  Haven't tested this but I would assume this is the case.

I'm sure the rest of the community can definitely add to the list above but I would say overall using enums is a good idea where it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think from a code perspective, enums definitely make sense.  However, if you are using NHibernate to generate your database schema, look out for it using MySQL's [Enum Data Type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html).  This will store your enums as strings, but enforce that only valid values are entered.  This can be costly from a storage perspective, and also when trying to refactor.  The enum database type will handle validation at the database level for you, so arbitrary updates will be less worrisome, I prefer storing the numeric value and relying on the application to validate, because it makes it easier to add or rename enum members.

I have no idea if this is the best approach or not (if you're using fluent nhibernate, this can almost certainly be accomplished using conventions) but if you look [at this blog post](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/EnterpriseDev/AppServer/quick-and-dirty-enum-mapper-for-fluent-n) you can find an IUserType that handles mapping enums as integers in MySQL and goes over some of the challenges encountered.